# Firemonkey TComboColorBox hiding color picker

Tags: firemonkey

Is there a way, after selection of a color, to programmatically hide the color picker of the TComboColorBox? I've searched on the web and Embarcadero community but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Just click on the component and the popup part will contract.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. Sorry. I'm editing the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no designed way to hide (collapse) the popup programmatically. And you did not explain why you think it would be necessary to have.

Keep in mind that there are 4 subcontrols, that the user may want to use:

- a `THueTrackBar`,
- an alpha channel trackbar,
- a color quad, and
- a hex color value edit box.

An automatic collapse of the popup would be just annoying.

The user can at any time decide to close the popup simply by clicking on the constantly visible bar.

---

With reference to your comment:

> *After your answer, I realized that I must implement a color picker component that shows a rect containing a TComboColorBox and a TButton as childs. Clicking the child button, in turn, hides the container rect itself.*

I have told you twice that the user can close the popup part of the `TComboColorBox` simply by clicking on the component (the base part of it).

In fact, the user can click anywhere outside of the popup window in order to close the popup window. The popup is closed immediately when the focus moves away from it.

In my opinion there's no need for a special "Close" button.

Comment: You're right, it makes no sense to hide the picker until the user is ok with the selected color.  After your answer, I realized that I must implement a color picker component that shows a rect containing a `TComboColorBox` and a `TButton` as childs. Clicking the child button, in turn, hides the container rect itself. I tested, temporarily, with a button and a rect container and works. Thanks.